# Python frame data optimization before sending through socket

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

Following step 6 of [Adrian's guide](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/) and some others, I managed to stream 320x240 frames with a speed of 10 fps and 0.1 s latency from my raspberry pi to my laptop. The problem is, when I test this system in my lab (which is equipped with an antique router), it can only stream 1-2 fps with a 1-1.5 second latency, which is totally unacceptable for what I intend to do with those frames.

Right now, my method is simple and straight forward: the server on the raspberry pi capture a frame and store it as a 320x240x3 matrix like the guide mentioned above, then pickle that matrix and keep pumping it over a TCP socket. The client on the laptop keep receiving these frames, do some processing on them, and finally show the result with imshow. My code is rather long for a post (around 200 lines) so I would rather avoid showing it if I can.

Is there any way to reduce the size of each frame's data (the pickled 320x240x3 matrix, its length is 230 kB) or is there a better way to transmit that data?

**EDIT:**

Okay guys, the exact presented length of the pickled array is 230563 bytes, and the payload data should be at least 230400 bytes so overhead should be no more than 0.07% of the total package size. I think this narrows the problem down to wireless connection quality and the method for encoding the data to bytes (pickling seems to be slow). The wireless problem can be solved by creating ad-hoc network (sounds interesting but I have not tried this yet) or simply buying a better router, and the encoding problem can be solved with Aaron's solution. Hope that this will help future readers :)

Comment: cv2.imencode can compress with jpeg or png for ecample. You could compress with gzip, too... But video streaming is typically done by video codecs like h264

Comment: When speed is your question, profiling is the answer. If I were to guess, it's `pickle` that's slowing you down.

Comment: I second @Aaron. Pickling is good for preprocessing and storing a large set of files, but there's no reason to pickle to stream the data. Pickling is for fast *unpacking* of data, but it can be larger in bytes than the data itself. Streaming the data itself would be better. There's also numpy's built in converters.

Comment: Depending on the application, the diffs between the frames could contain much less entropy than each individual frame. Treating it as an actual stream of images and compressing it along the time dimension could make sense for example if the frames consist mostly of static background.

Comment: Thank you for your replies guys. I attach the raspberry pi on a robot to control it and it will move a lot, so the background will change, very fast even.

And I considered using h.264 too, but [articles like this](http://video-codecs.blogspot.de/2008/06/understanding-various-video-codecs.html) suggest that it is not friendly with constrained hardware (raspberry pi is not that fast and the lab router is an antique).

Comment: It seems to be the network that's the cause of an issue. Can you perhaps invest in a less antique router? You could look into low latency TCP techniques, or if you can afford losing some frames, build something upon UDP. For compression, you probably want lossless if you're analyzing the data. And something lightweight, since it's an embedded system.

Comment: Is that connection over WiFi? It's kinda hard to imagine something this bad over a wire these days. If so, maybe there's a lot of interference there? Either other networks on the same channel, or perhaps some other 2.4GHz equipment. Check into that, and maybe consider switching over to 5Ghz link. | If it's wired, can you just ditch the router and run a direct cable?

Comment: @Dan Mašek Yeah it is over wifi, and there are like 10 other networks from nearby labs so the interference is really bad too. I will need to steer the robot like a car between two white lines using CNN on the frames (and some object detection, if I can push it), so further image quality drop and frame loss are the last things I want. Therefore, UDP is a big no unfortunately. Maybe I will have to resort to pestering my professor to finally buy a new router after all :(

Comment: Maybe look into creating an ad-hoc network between the robot and the computer that does the processing. Basically a direct link between the two machines. A reliable communication channel will be essential when it's part of a control loop like in your case.

Comment: Okay, ad-hoc is an interesting suggestion, I will definitely try this, thank you :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr**: `struct` is actually slow.. Instead of `pickle` use `np.ndarray.tobytes()` combined with `np.frombuffer()` to eliminate overhead.

I'm not well versed in `opencv`, which is probably the best answer, but a drop-in approach to speeding up transfer could be to use `struct` to pack and unpack the data to be sent over the network instead of `pickle`.

Here's an example of sending a `numpy` array of known dimensions over a socket using `struct`

```
import numpy as np
import socket
import struct

#----- server ------
conn = socket.socket()
#connect socket somewhere
arr = np.random.randint(0,256,(320,240,3), dtype="B") # unsigned bytes "B": camera likely returns 0-255 pixel values
conn.write(struct.pack('230400B', *arr.flat)) #230400 unsigned bytes

#----- client ------
conn = socket.socket()
#connect socket somewhere
data = conn.read(230400) #read 230400 bytes
arr = np.array(struct.unpack('230400B', data), dtype='B').reshape((320,240,3),)
```

**EDIT**

A little digging shows numpy has a `tobytes` function that exposes a memory view of the data as a `bytes` object. This basically does the work of struct without needing the argument unpacking in the function call to encode. This prompted me to also see if we could do the unpacking too, and as long as you're okay with flying by the seat of your pants a little bit (interruptions or errors would not be caught gracefully), we can pack and unpack the data with almost zero overhead making the only limiting factor your network.

testing script:

```
arr = np.random.randint(0,256,(320,240,3), dtype="B") # unsigned bytes "B": camera likely returns 0-255 pixel values

t = time()
for _ in range(100):
    arr2 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(arr))
print(f'pickle pack, pickle unpack: {time()-t} sec')

t = time()
for _ in range(100):
    arr2 = np.array(struct.unpack('230400B', struct.pack('230400B', *arr.flat)), dtype='B').reshape((320,240,3),)
print(f'struct pack, struct unpack: {time()-t} sec')

t = time()
for _ in range(100):
    arr2 = np.array(struct.unpack('230400B', arr.tobytes()), dtype='B').reshape((320,240,3),)
print(f'numpy pack, struct unpack: {time()-t} sec')

t = time()
for _ in range(100):
    arr2 = np.frombuffer(arr.tobytes(), dtype="B").reshape((320,240,3),)
print(f'numpy pack, numpy unpack: {time()-t} sec')
```

prints:

```
pickle pack, pickle unpack: 0.005013704299926758 sec
struct pack, struct unpack: 3.558577299118042 sec
numpy pack, struct unpack: 1.2988512516021729 sec
numpy pack, numpy unpack: 0.0010025501251220703 sec
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow morning. There are a bunch of jumper wires connecting the pi and the robot so I left it at the lab with the robot.

Comment: I'll give you a plus, since this avoids the unnecessary overhead of pickling the data. It's quite relevant to OpenCV too, since the Python bindings use `numpy.array`s to represent the image. I'd probably pack some metadata (size + channel count) before the pixel array to make the protocol more flexible (doesn't cost much). | Overall I don't really think this is a solution based on what OP mentioned in comments. Unreliable comms are the issue, and IMHO that doesn't go well with low cost hardware and easy solutions.

Comment: I'd even consider throwing in some relatively lightweight compression there, like `zlib` or `lz4` on the buffer, or even doing a `cv2.imencode` into a PNG (that's basically zlib with a choice of few simple predictors).

Comment: @BaoTran testing is king... `struct` is apparently much slower, but `numpy.frombuffer(arr.tobytes())` is about 3x faster than `pickle` according to my testing. ymmv, and it seems like network stability is your bigger issue, but every little bit helps right?

Comment: @Aaron maybe scale the times by the number of iterations? This looks a bit misleading (although the proportions are still correct).

Comment: @DanMašek all I was going for was comparison.. the network will realistically be the slowest part. I did further testing where I ditched the middle 2 conditions, and used an array with shape (3200,2400,3) to get my 3x speed value to make sure loop overhead wasn't the biggest factor.

Comment: I have a couple of questions about your answer - I normally code in C or C++ and am new to Python. You have `arr = np.random.randint(0,255...` but as far as I can tell that will never generate 255, only up to 254. Am I mistaken, or is there some reason for that please?

Comment: A further question, in C or C++, a send or a read on a TCP socket is not guaranteed to return all the bytes requested so you normally have to put it in a loop in case the image gets split because of the MTU or any restrictions on the network. Do your `conn.write()` and `conn.read()` guarantee to send/receive all the requested bytes in Python? Thank you if you have time to answer.

Comment: @MarkSetchell 255 v.s. 256 was an oversight on my part... you are correct. I'm not sure about your question on sockets, I mostly just assumed for the purpose of this question that they work like any other file-like object.. They may require some additional structure to make sure the whole buffer gets sent / read.

Comment: Ok, thank you... I'm just learning all the Python stuff and not too sure of things :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell IMHO, python has one of the best standard documentation websites out there. [here's](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#socket-howto) the quickstart on sockets in python

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge and time.

Answer (score 2):

Since the communication speed and latency are good with a good communication link, you're probably already limited by the performance of the Raspberry regarding the frame rate. You might gain a little (if you haven't done this already) by running the image acquisition and communications in separate threads (in Python it may need to be separate processes to avoid the GIL).

Of course, avoiding any unnecessary overhead, such as what [Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3220135/aaron) describes in his answer, especially when it's easy to do, is worth it.

I'd even consider using some lightweight compression. Python provides `zlib`, which you can tune to trade compression ratio for CPU usage. There's also `bzip2` and since Python 3.3 `lzma` although those are more CPU intensive. You can also get bindings for things like `lz4` or `snappy` which go on the opposite end of the spectrum.

Another alternative is using [`cv2.imencode`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga461f9ac09887e47797a54567df3b8b63) (and `cv2.imdecode` on the other end) with some compressed format. Since you will be processing the images, a lossless codec would seem appropriate, so PNG might be a good choice (it's basically `zlib` with a few simple predictors).

As always whenever performance is critical, benchmark the various approaches so you can find out which suits you best.

---

If you actually had a 320x240 resolution camera, I'd suggest transmitting the raw Bayer CFA data (usually colour cameras are monochrome arrays with a special colour filter). That would mean transmitting 1/3 of the data compared to RGB format (and you'd do the demosaicing on the other end). However, as this is an already scaled down image from a 5 megapixel camera, it won't help here.

---

However, the critical things about the problem you mentioned:

- The connection is over WiFi
- There are 10 other WiFi networks around
- The WiFi router you're using is ancient (so quite likely just 2.4 GHz)

Even at the best rate, you're transmitting barely 3 megabytes per second. That's not that much, so I'd look into improving the connection somehow. There are tools that allow you to scan for all the neighboring networks. Use one of them to find the least congested channel (keep in mind the overlap). Maybe you just switching to a better channel will improve the situation.

If at all possible, you may want to use 5GHz, since this tends to be much less congested. However the ancient router may prevent that. You could look into creating an ad-hoc network between the two machines, which is basically a direct connection that does not involve any intermediate routers.

Otherwise consider investing into a better router, and making sure you get a reliable communication link. I don't think there's much of a choice if the link is part of the control loop as in your case.

---

Edit: Oh, and perhaps a directional antenna on the stationary machine?

Answer (score 1):

I have been investigating just about all the options for transmitting images from a RaspberryPi over wifi - to a Mac, but the receiver could be anything.

I decided to transmit the data in its YUV420p format as that takes the least network bandwidth - **HALF** that required by RGB data. I tried disabling noise-reduction increasing the ISO and everything I could imagine to make it go faster and analysed the whole thing with a very cool little logic analyser I got from Amazon for £12 ($15) and the `sigrok` logic analyser software.

Here's how I can get 36 frames per second of 320x240 pixels:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import io
import socket
import struct
import time
import picamera

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# Enable GPIO pins as output for Logic Analyser probe-based debugging
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)

WIDTH=320
HEIGHT=240
BUFFERSIZE=WIDTH*HEIGHT*3//2
PORT=8000
SERVER='192.168.0.8'
client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect((SERVER, PORT))
connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')
try:
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
        camera.framerate = 60
        time.sleep(2)
        start = time.time()
        count = 0
        stream = io.BytesIO()
        # Use the video-port for captures...
        while True:
            GPIO.output(20,GPIO.HIGH)
            frame=next(camera.capture_continuous(stream, format="yuv", use_video_port=True))
            GPIO.output(20,GPIO.LOW)
            stream.seek(0)
            GPIO.output(22,GPIO.HIGH)
            connection.write(stream.read())
            GPIO.output(22,GPIO.LOW)
            count += 1
            if time.time() - start > 15:
                break
            stream.seek(0)
            stream.truncate()
    #connection.write(struct.pack('<L', 0))
finally:
    connection.close()
    client_socket.close()
    finish = time.time()
print('Sent %d images in %d seconds at %.2ffps' % (
    count, finish-start, count / (finish-start)))
GPIO.cleanup()
```

On the Mac, running as a server and display:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import io
import socket
import struct
import numpy as np
import cv2

WIDTH=320
HEIGHT=240
PORT=8000
BUFFERSIZE=WIDTH*HEIGHT*3//2
print("Running on port {}: width={}, height={}".format(PORT,WIDTH,HEIGHT))

# Start a socket listening for connections on all interfaces
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', PORT))
server_socket.listen(0)

frame=0

# Accept a single connection and make a file-like object out of it
connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('rb')
try:
    while True:
        # Construct a stream and fill with image data from network
        image_stream = io.BytesIO()
        image_stream.write(connection.read(BUFFERSIZE))
        # Rewind the stream, and process
        image_stream.seek(0)
        img_str=image_stream.read()
        nparr=np.fromstring(img_str,np.uint8)
        # Data layout is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#/media/File:Yuv420.svg
        Y=nparr[0:WIDTH*HEIGHT].reshape(HEIGHT,WIDTH)
        # ssU = sub-sampled U channel, ssV = sub-sampled V channel
        ssU=nparr[WIDTH*HEIGHT:WIDTH*HEIGHT*5//4].reshape(HEIGHT//2,WIDTH//2)
        ssV=nparr[WIDTH*HEIGHT*5//4:].reshape(HEIGHT//2,WIDTH//2)
        # Up-sample the U and V channels to full size
        U=cv2.resize(ssU,(WIDTH,HEIGHT),cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        V=cv2.resize(ssV,(WIDTH,HEIGHT),cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        # Combine the YUV into single image and convert to BGR
        oc_YUV=cv2.merge((Y,U,V))
        oc_BGR=cv2.cvtColor(oc_YUV,cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR)
        # That's actually it, but I upscale for better viewing on screen
        tmp=cv2.resize(oc_BGR,(WIDTH*2,HEIGHT*2),cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        cv2.imshow('image',tmp)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        frame=frame+1
finally:
    connection.close()
    server_socket.close()
```

Here's a little video of it running. It is extremely responsive and the jerkiness is only down to the fact that I resampled the screen capture down to 2fps to get it under the StackOverflow 2MB limit.

You can safely ignore all the GPIO-related stuff in the code - that just wiggles pins high and low on the logic analyser so I can time things accurately.

[image]

The YUV data are laid out like this:

[image]

> By Original bitmapped version by Xburge03, SVG version by Qef. - Vectorised version of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image:Yuv420.png – created with a program given on the talk page., Public Domain, https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?curid=18105371

---

Given that your issues seem to be with the network bandwidth, my approach is based on sending YUV data, as above. I also looked at Dan's suggestion of compressing the data and, whilst the bandwidth reduction is obviously dependent on your lighting and your subject matter, the YUV data does lend itself to some `lz4` compression. I saw around 25% further reduction in network bandwidth and no perceptible increase in latency. The code looks like this:

```
import lz4.frame
...
compressed=lz4.frame.compress(data,compression_level=lz4.frame.COMPRESSIONLEVEL_MINHC))
```